# Problems after generating the exe from a py file

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python Version 3.7.3 and PyInstaller 3.5. I have written a Python script named `read.py` which will read the scanned PDF and convert it to a text file. I could successfully generate the exe using the PyInstaller commands `pyi-makespec --onefile read.py` and `pyinstaller --onefile read.spec`. The .exe file is working fine in my system where i have all the packages installed, but when I tried to run it on a different Windows PC where the Python packages are not available, it is looking for the `poppler` module.

I even tried to add the hook file for poppler in pyinstaller hooks folder but it did not take this hook file while generating the .exe file.

Please help to resolve this issue, or please let me know if there is any other way to generate the exe without having the dependencies on the Python supporting files.

Below is the error which I'm getting when I execute the .exe file on a different PC:

```
File "read_image.py", line 29, in <module> 
File "site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 54, in convert_from_path 
File "site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 244, in _page_count pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH? [17920] Failed to execute script read_image
```

Thanks for the Help...

Comment: have your tried the ```--hidden-import``` argument, to include any module your script is looking for on different  PC

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm getting error in poppler path. The poppler path is present in the environmental variables in the system where the .py file is developed. So i'm not getting any error in the developed PC. where as this poppler path is not available in any other PC where i'm trying to get the .exe executed.  So is there any way to include this environmental variable path in .exe file so that it will work in any other PC even when the packages are not installed and path is not available in Environmental variable of that PC.

Comment: The below is the error snippet which i'm getting when i execute my .exe file in different PC: File "read_image.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 54, in convert_from_path
  File "site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 244, in _page_count
pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?
[17920] Failed to execute script read_image

Comment: I made an update to your question to include the error message.  
looks like your script relies on a third party binary tool, and the tool binary path must somehow  in the $PATH environment variable. 
to include the tool in your .exe as well , by ```--add-binary``` [doc here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search) and [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#how-the-one-file-program-works) ,  

but I have no idear how poppler works with you script.....